# How to select the value of a substitution rule for a particular variable?

Tags: replacement, rule

Say I have the following lists of rules:

```
case1 = {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4, e -> 5}
case2 = {c -> 3, a -> 1, w -> 2}
case3 = {x -> 5, y -> 2, z -> 0, c -> 2}
```

How do I write a function `myfun[]`, to select the value of "c" in each case?

I want

```
myfun[case1]
```

to return 4;

```
myfun[case2]
```

to return 3;

```
myfun[case3]
```

to return 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to @belisarius' use of formal symbols to overcome the problem caused by c having been assigned a value

```
case1 = {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4, e -> 5};
case2 = {c -> 3, a -> 1, w -> 2};
case3 = {x -> 5, y -> 2, z -> 0, c -> 2};

myfun[x_] := Cases[x, (c -> val_) :> val][[1]]

myfun /@ {case1, case2, case3}
```

> {4, 3, 2}

```
c = 5;

myfun /@ {case1, case2, case3}
```

> {4, 3, 2}

Comment: It works until I do something stupid like `c = 2; a = 2; w = 2;`

Comment: Actually, there is no difference between this solution and belisarius's `c/.x`. It is not solving the problem with c having an assigned value.

Comment: @belisarius Actually it suffices that c=a.

Answer (score 9):

```
myfun[x_] := c /. x
myfun /@ {case1, case2, case3}
(* {4, 3, 2} *)
```

But please note that if you inadvertently assign a value to the symbol `c`, it goes astray and can't be repaired by tricks done only on `myfun[]` since it "corrupts" your cases lists.
Considering the above, perhaps it is safer to work with Formal symbols if you really need this kind of construct.

```
case1F = {\[FormalA] -> 1, \[FormalB] -> 3, \[FormalC] ->  4, \[FormalE] -> 5};
myfun1[x_] := \[FormalC] /. x
myfun1[case1F]
(*4*)
```

Comment: +1.  One can also use strings, `"a"`, `"b"`, etc., if longer, more descriptive names are desirable, such `"cat"`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 [Or a formal cat](http://www.skeezixthecat.com/scratchingpost/uploaded_images/formal-776883.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

In such a case, with Mathematica 10, one can use easily associations:

```
case1 = {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 4, e -> 5}
case2 = {c -> 3, a -> 1, w -> 2}
case3 = {x -> 5, y -> 2, z -> 0, c -> 2}
```

then:

```
ac1 = Association@case1;
ac2 = Association@case2;
ac3 = Association@case3
```

The associated value for the key "c" one gets in the following way:

```
 ac2[Key[c]]
```

the associated value 3. The whole thing is more easy when the keys are strings, in this case you can simply write ac2["c"].